# Credit usage when Google Places API does not return Place ID

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-premium-plan

I'm looking to store Google Place ID for several different places (millions of records). I have purchased a premium plan usage.

Will Google deduct my credits for those records which don't have a Place ID (or Place ID is not returned) ?

Answer (score 3):

Maps API Credits are deducted based on the number of requests made to the Places API, not the values or fields like Place ID, returned within those requests.  Credits will be consumed anytime the request doesn't return an error so if you're getting some results (or `ZERO_RESULTS`), credits are being consumed.

As a Google Maps API Premium Plan customer, feel free to contact the [support team](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support) for these sort of questions.